# Java library for writing a table on the command line

Tags: java, command-line

Does anybody know a library that would transform a String[][] into a String table as below?

```
| title1 | title2 |
|________|________|
| blah   | blih   |
| blah2  | blih2  |
etc...
```

I could write formatted strings for this, but it will be non-generic code, tied to the parameters.
Writing generic code for this purpose would be more expensive than what I'm willing to invest.

So all in all, I think a library would be justified for this.

Any idea if this exists already?

Comment: Could us use a csv format and view in open office or excel?

Comment: What's wrong with `String.format()`?

Comment: String.format() is good, it just doesn't give the logic to calculate the width of the columns or adapt the table to different number of columns according different String[][] input.

Comment: And if library there is, I would also expect that the library takes lists of more sophisticated objects in input and serialize them in a table manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [daniel_or_else](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016448/daniel-or-else) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20771871) thread:

Using [j-text-utils](https://code.google.com/p/j-text-utils/) you may print to console a table like:

```
_____________________________________________________________
| Item Num | Description           | Rating |  Cost | Price |
=============================================================
| 8675309  | Tommy Tutone Album    |      3 |  5.99 | 10.99 |
| 5619452  | Led Zeppelin Box Set  |      5 | 10.42 | 24.95 |
| 9154732  | Justin Bieber Box Set |     -1 |  0.00 |  0.00 |
```

And it as simple as:

```
TextTable tt = new TextTable(columnNames, data);
tt.printTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any library that does this, but take a look at this SO question:

[Java: Print a 2D String array as a right-justified table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275338/java-print-a-2d-string-array-as-a-right-justified-table)

It shows you how you can create a generic method which dynamically-generates format strings for each column.

Comment: This is a good solution, but if a library exists, I would still like to know, as I need more formatting features in my case. 
Actually I'm not looking for a solution, more a library to externalize this kind of logic (if I can avoid maintaining my ugly code, I will :-)).